# Show document for selected API

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any shortcut key in Android Studio to to show document for selected API? How can I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Keyboard Commands given in the Studio Tips & Trick documentation.

In windows  : **CTRL + ALT + L**

In Macintosh : **OPTOIN + CMD + L**